# Getting data (json) but saving as Str

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a code with which I can call data from url every 5 secodns and save it in a csv file:

```
   import time

   run_time = 30
   run_until = time.time() + run_time
   while time.time() < run_until:
       url = 'http://xxx'
       csv_file = open('cam_data2.csv', 'a')
       req = requests.get(url)
       data = req.json()
       csv_file.write(str(data))     #here I have to concade the value to str
       csv_file.write('\n')
       time.sleep(5)
       csv_file.close()
```

Now my problem is that I am working with this tipe of data:
{"blood_pressure_diastolic_value":70.0,"blood_pressure_systolic_value":120.0}

and the csv_file.write() method only allows me to save it as a string. Is there any other way that the json structure stays as it is so that I can later recall the value of each item?

Comment: why can't you write the data to json file instead of csv?

Comment: Why not just use `json.loads` to get it back to "json structure" after reading back from CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i would suggest to save it as json file instead of csv. But,if you still want to write to csv you can follow.

```
   import time
   import json



   run_time = 30
   run_until = time.time() + run_time
   while time.time() < run_until:
       url = 'http://xxx'
       csv_file = open('cam_data2.csv', 'a')
       req = requests.get(url)
       data = req.json()
       # dumps the data using json library
       csv_file.write(json.dumps(data)) 
       csv_file.write('\n')
       time.sleep(5)
       csv_file.close()
```

Comment: thx for the answer. How would you save it as json file insted? Later I have to compare this dataset with another. So to get the value of each item json wpuld be good

Comment: https://jsonlines.org/ might be a more suitable format, there's a python package available if you want to use it https://pypi.org/project/json-lines/

Comment: @WonderWoman , there could be a better way to do this , can you tell me exactly what are you trying to do and how does your sample data looks like ?

Comment: @Atif I've 2 Datasets. They are a bit larger than the following examples (one dataset every 5 seconds for 10minutes):

1) json (for which i use the code above): {"blood_pressure_diastolic_value":70.0,"blood_pressure_systolic_value":120.0}

2) And a csv file that is saved in excel with a header and its given values.
Time,RelativeTime,SystemLocalTime,NOM_PRESS_BLD_NONINV_SYS,NOM_PRESS_BLD_NONINV_DIA
09-11-2022 14:56:57.120,4055270912,09-11-2022 14:56:29.981,70,120

For every timestamp I want to compare the values that correspond to the same attribute to see if the comparison is accurate

Comment: @WonderWoman in that case you can save the data in line delimited json since json library supports line delimited JSON